# Correct way to convert method to async in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm attempting to convert the following method (simplified example) to be asynchronous, as the `cacheMissResolver` call may be expensive in terms of time (database lookup, network call):

```
// Synchronous version
public class ThingCache
{
    private static readonly object _lockObj;
    // ... other stuff

    public Thing Get(string key, Func<Thing> cacheMissResolver)
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
            return cache[key];

        Thing item;

        lock(_lockObj)
        {
            if (cache.Contains(key))
                return cache[key];

            item = cacheMissResolver();    
            cache.Add(key, item);
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

There are plenty of materials on-line about consuming async methods, but the advice I have found on producing them seems less clear-cut. Given that this is intended to be part of a library, are either of my attempts below correct?

```
// Asynchronous attempts
public class ThingCache
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lockObj = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    // ... other stuff

    // attempt #1
    public async Task<Thing> Get(string key, Func<Thing> cacheMissResolver)
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
            return await Task.FromResult(cache[key]);

        Thing item;

        await _lockObj.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (cache.Contains(key))
                return await Task.FromResult(cache[key]);

            item = await Task.Run(cacheMissResolver).ConfigureAwait(false);
            _cache.Add(key, item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockObj.Release();
        }

        return item;
    }

    // attempt #2
    public async Task<Thing> Get(string key, Func<Task<Thing>> cacheMissResolver)
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
            return await Task.FromResult(cache[key]);

        Thing item;

        await _lockObj.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (cache.Contains(key))
                return await Task.FromResult(cache[key]);

            item = await cacheMissResolver().ConfigureAwait(false);
            _cache.Add(key, item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockObj.Release();
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

Is using `SemaphoreSlim` the correct way to replace a lock statement in an async method? (I can't await in the body of a lock statement.)

Should I make the `cacheMissResolver` argument of type `Func<Task<Thing>>` instead? Although this puts the burden of making sure the resolver func is async on the caller (wrapping in `Task.Run`, I know it will be offloaded to a background thread if it takes a long time).

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock).

Comment: @dbc - in the real code cache is an instance of InMemoryCache; but it could be any suitable structure. I didn't want to complicate the example.

Comment: @rob It's highly relevant though, because you're accessing the data structure from multiple threads at the same time, and most aren't built to support that.  It would need to be a data structure specifically designed to support it, such as a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: @Servy - Its an instance of System.Runtime.MemoryCache, so thread safe according to Msdn docs. The wrapper class does some other book keeping, so needed its own synchronisation code. The simplified example obscured that, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @servy - perhaps my understanding of async is wrong. I appreciate the lock will stop things running in parallel, but the async / await will allow the method to yield if the resolver takes a long time to run. Or have I got that wrong? Thanks - this is all useful.

Comment: @rob Sorry, I mixed this question up with another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using SemaphoreSlim the correct way to replace a lock statement in an async method?

Yes.

> Should I make the `cacheMissResolver` argument of type `Func<Task<Thing>>` instead?

Yes.  It'll allow the caller to provide an inherently asynchronous operation (such as IO) rather than making this only suitable for work that is long running *CPU bound* work.  (While still supporting CPU bound work by simply having the caller use `Task.Run` themselves, if that's what they want to do.)

---

Other than that, just note that there's not point in having `await Task.FromResult(...);`  Wrapping a value in a `Task` just to immediately unwrap it is pointless.  Just use the result directly in such situations, in this case, return the cached value directly.  What you're doing isn't really *wrong*, it's just needlessly complicating/confusing the code.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't grasped the implications of using await on Task.FromResult(...).

Answer (score 3):

If your cache is in-memory (it looks like it is), then consider caching the *tasks* rather than the *results*. This has a nice side property if two methods request the same key, only a single resolving request is made. Also, since only the cache is locked (and not the resolving operations), you can continue using a simple lock.

```
public class ThingCache
{
  private static readonly object _lockObj;

  public async Task<Thing> GetAsync(string key, Func<Task<Thing>> cacheMissResolver)
  {
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
      if (cache.Contains(key))
        return cache[key];
      var task = cacheMissResolver();
      _cache.Add(key, task);
    }
  }
}
```

However, this will also cache exceptions, which you may not want. One way to avoid this is to permit the exception task to enter the cache initially, but then prune it when the next request is made:

```
public class ThingCache
{
  private static readonly object _lockObj;

  public async Task<Thing> GetAsync(string key, Func<Task<Thing>> cacheMissResolver)
  {
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
      if (cache.Contains(key))
      {
        if (cache[key].Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
          return cache[key];
        cache.Remove(key);
      }
      var task = cacheMissResolver();
      _cache.Add(key, task);
    }
  }
}
```

You may decide this extra check is unnecessary if you have another process pruning the cache periodically.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadn't thought about caching the Tasks themselves. Cheers also for writing so much on the topic, found a number of your articles useful in learning more!